# Using System.ServiceProcess in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to gain access to the `ServiceController` class from within a custom build activity.

So far here is the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Test.Build.Activities
{
    public sealed class ResetCaches : CodeActivity
    {
        int timeWaited = 0;

        ServiceController Services();
    }
{
```

The error I'm seeing is for the `ServiceController Services();` declaration:

```
The type or namespace ServiceController could not be found
```

I'm pretty new to C# (I've been using VB mostly) but I thought I would be able to reference the classes within `ServiceProcess` by pulling it in through a `using` statement.

For reference, I'm going off of the information at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) article.

If I'm missing some key concept, just point me in the right direction and I'm happy to do more investigation on my end.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.ServiceProcess? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference in the project to **System.ServiceProcess.dll**.

Comment: Wow, that was a really dumb mistake. Thanks, I was expecting the compiler to show me an error if there was a missing reference after I tried to pull in the system.ServiceProcess. There's my (dumb) assumption.